# using hash() for load balancing

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am intending to use [hash()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hashfunction) function for load balancing -- so I can divide data into uniformly distributed chunks for performance optimization -- but the documentation says that as of now it uses xxhash algorithm and it may change in the future abruptly (I suppose without notice). I am not storing result of hash , but for me invovation of `hash()` may not happen in the same query. So lets say I am trying to use it like this:-

```
.append async MyTable <| Query | where hash(somecolumn,4) == 0

.append async MyTable <| Query | where hash(somecolumn,4) == 1

.append async MyTable <| Query | where hash(somecolumn,4) == 2

.append async MyTable <| Query | where hash(somecolumn,4) == 3
```

These will execute as separate queries in sequence. Sometime in the future the algorithm behind the method will change. Ideally all the 4 queries will be summited around the same time but there is always a very minute time gap and suddenly ADX team performs a switch to new algorithm , then some of these query statements will use older algorithm while the rest will newer algorithm -- causing totally illogical results for us -- as some data will not be pulled and some data may get duplicated. Is there any recommendation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to the implementation of the the `hash()` function, while possible, aren't as frequent as you fear they would be.

Still, if you want to get 100% reassurance, you could choose using a different (though less performant) implementation, that is guaranteed to remain consistent. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sha256hashfunction or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/md5hashfunction

FWIW, I would recommend that you stick to `hash()`, and/or if possible - 'partition' your data using a different set of filters, based on your knowledge of the data set (e.g. datetime filters, knowing that there's no late-arriving data)